# How to translate kotlin to java?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
private val mapObjectTapListener = object : MapObjectTapListener {
    override fun onMapObjectTap(mapObject: MapObject, point: Point): Boolean{
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Эрмитаж — музей изобразительных искусств", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return true
    }
 }
```

what would this code look like in Java?

try translate this

```
  private void mapObjectTapListener = MapObjectTapListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMapObjectTap(mapObject,point){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Эрмитаж — музей изобразительных искусств", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is not tested in any way, I just wrote this in the Stack Overflow's box, **use it carefully**:

```
private final MapObjectTapListener mapObjectTapListener = new MapObjectTapListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectTap(MapObject mapObject, Point point) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Эрмитаж — музей изобразительных искусств", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Technically, if you wanted to match it 1-to-1, you would say `var` instead of the actual type. That would help you match the `val` in the Kotlin example.

Comment: @davidalayachew You wouldn't be able to use `var`, because in Java `var` only works for local variables, not for fields.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, right you are. Ty vm